# Can CopyOnWriteArrayList be used with mutable objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I'm using a collection

```
    CopyOnWriteArrayList<X> myCOW =  new CopyOnWriteArrayList<X>();
```

where X is a mutable object. I know that from Java Concurrency in Practice that "the copy-on-write collections derive their thread-safety from the  fact that as long as an effectively immutable object is properly published, no further synchronization is required when accessing it."

I iterate over the collection:

```
   for (X x : myCOW) {
    if (conditionIsMet) {
       x.modify(); // modify() is a synchronized method in class X
    }
   }
```

My question is if this way of doing exposes me to thread-safety problems? My guess is that not, since the X's modify() method is synchronized.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a class and a collection which is thread safe, they can be used together in a thread safe manner.  There can be gotchas, but I don't see any in your example.

Comment: But if the modify() method wouldn't be synchronized, then it would be a problem, no?

Comment: @ovdsrn: yes, if your `X` class is not itself thread-safe, then you can get ugly effects from concurrent access to it. That doesn't mean that the `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is broken, 'though.

Comment: It would be a potential problem for the component, the collection will still be fine. It is possible to write a thread safe component without synchronized.

Comment: I guess thats what `CopyOnWriteArrayList ` does.